# How to get actual size of centimeter or millimeter in screen using React-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How to get actual size of centimeter or millimeter in screen using React-native?

I'm working on a project that requires to show the actual size of a certain image to screen.

e.g 10cm (width) and 10cm (height).

A code that I can be referenced.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use React Native‘s PixelRatio API to get the screens pixel density, and then calculate pixels to centimetres using that.

For example if the density is 2: 126p per centimetre